# What does it mean when entries in Android DDMS GL tracer are red?

Tags: android, opengl-es, ddms

What does it mean if entries in a DDMS gl trace are red? I know draw-calls are blue.

[image: DDMS gl trace]

Comment: My guess would be calls that are functional no-ops. Like setting non-existent uniforms.

Comment: @NicolBolas But they take 10 nanoseconds, about as much as all the other allocations..

Comment: They're not "allocations"; they're just uploading. And 10ns is *miniscule*, even when dealing with a goal of 60-120fps. 10ns is what you would expect from calling a trivial, non-inlined function ~5,000 times. Are you sure those are in nanoseconds and not microseconds?